# If value "1" display picture

Tags: php, html, json, if-statement, html-table

***The result that I need to reach***

> If the value in the "price" column is "1" and in the "code" column is
> 5, then display the "images/imagex.png" image. If the value in the
> "price" column is "2" and in the "code" column is 5, then it will show
> the image "images/imagey.png".

***Information:*** *The table name in the database is "mag", it is updated every 5m, so every 5m the php page would have to be updated also with new information as well.*

---

I've tried a lot of things and looked for several guides, so far I understand that I'll need to use a JSON, right? I do not know very well about it, but I understood that it updates without needing to refresh the page (f5).

The table looks like this:

```
  <div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg">
  <tr>
  <th class="tg-031e" colspan="3"><img src="images/123_01.png" alt=""></th>
  </tr>
  
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><img src="images/123_02.png" alt=""></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><img src="images/123_03.png" alt=""></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><img src="images/1234_04.png" alt="">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

With the code it would look like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mag2";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

// Show images
 <div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg">
      <tr>
   <th class="tg-031e" colspan="3">if($row['price, code']=='1, 5'){
 print "<img src='images/123_01.png'/>";
}
></th>
      </tr>
      
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-031e">if($row['price, code']=='3, 4'){
 print "<img src='images/123_02.png'/>";
}
</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">if($row['price, code']=='54, 12'){
 print "<img src='images/123_03.png'/>";
}
</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">if($row['price, code']=='11, 31'){
 print "<img src='images/123_04.png'/>";
}
</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
} // End while loop
?>
```

I tried to explain everything I can, I apologize for being a bit confused, I'm starting and I really tried my best, but I do not find a solution.

## edit

My

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Cod_Codes";
 $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
 $query->execute();
 $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
?>
```

Then in my table:

```
<?php foreach( $results as $row ){
   echo "<tr><td>";
    if($row['Cod_Mwy'] == 7 && $row['Cod_Miee'] == 5) {
 echo '<img src="/images/'.$photo->t1.png.'"/>';
    }
     echo "</td>";
?>
```

The picture doesnt appear yet. I have tried showing just the values and worked. So is not a problem with DB or something like this... (I think haha)

Thanks again!

## edit

My table:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;padding: 0px;background-color: #6479cd;}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}
    .tg-031e img {max-width:100%;align-content: center;margin:0px;margin:0px auto;padding: 0px;}
    td, tr, img  { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    </style>
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e" colspan="3"><img src="images/TELA-MONITOR-USAR_01.png" alt=""></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">'
     <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
    if($row['Cod_Usuario'] == 12 && $row['Cod_Propriedade_Maquina'] == 68) 
 echo '<img src="images/logo.png"/>';
echo '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
       }
    
       ?>
</table>
</div>
```

The entire file:

```
<?php
 $user = 'xxx';
 $pass = 'xxx';
 $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=xxx;dbname=test', $user, $pass );
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_test";
 $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
 $query->execute();
 $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 
?>
 <html>
 <body>
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;padding: 0px;background-color: #6479cd;}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}
    .tg-031e img {max-width:100%;align-content: center;margin:0px;margin:0px auto;padding: 0px;}
    td, tr, img  { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    </style>
    
    <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
echo '<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg">';
  echo '<tr> <th class="tg-031e" colspan="3"><img src="images/topo" alt=""></th>';
  echo '</tr> <tr> <td class="tg-031e">';
    if($row['Cod_Usuario'] == 12 && $row['Cod_Propriedade_Maquina'] == 68) 
 echo '<img src="images/1.png"/>';
    
   echo '</td><td class="tg-031e"><img src="images/2.png" alt="">';
   echo '</td> <td class="tg-031e"><img src="images/3.png" alt="">';
      echo '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    
echo '</table></div>';
        }
       ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the if check must be like this if($row['price'] == 1 && $row['code'] == 5){ .... }

Comment: please, note that `mysql_query` was deprecated years ago and is declared obsolete after PHP 5.5 (even removed in the PHP 7.0, which you should be using...) http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php you should use mysqli instead http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu)

Comment: @AbidNawaz Thanks for answer me. But the code doesn't work yet. I did these changes and doesn't show any picture yet. Any suggestion? Do you have some "example"?

Comment: @Gabriel which php version you are using ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz my version is: PHP Version 5.6.31

Comment: @Gabriel the mysql_query is deprecated in PHP 5.6 use mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are using is invalid. Use correct path like this.

```
 <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
  echo "<tr><td>";
  if($row['Cod_Mwy'] == 7 && $row['Cod_Miee'] == 5) {
     echo '<img src="images/your image name here"/>';
  }
  echo "</td></tr>";
  }
?>
```

Also if $results is php object then you will use -> to point to the key.

```
 <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
  echo "<tr><td>";
  if($row->Cod_Mwy == 7 && $row->Cod_Miee == 5) {
     echo '<img src="images/your image name here"/>';
  }
  echo "</td></tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @AbidNawaz ! Just one question: my table is not working with css (the values from css).

Comment: how you have assigned the css classes to table?

Comment: I hava edited my post with the table right now, its the same css (style) but they are not working.

Comment: @Gabriel https://fiddle.jshell.net/marwat/ygh9cL06/ . Also read this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: Hey, thanks man. The table is working without the php code.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/srxfqyc2/1/
But if I try to insert the php code that we are talking about, stop working... crushed the page.

Comment: have you inserted the php code to fiddle.jshell.net ?

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/srxfqyc2/5/ 
try now... I will give you my life man, you deserve it.

Comment: @Gabriel hahaha PHP does not work in jsfiddle, it only supports javascript

Comment: Now I have edited the question with the entire file. Works? haha

Answer (score 0):

This is a string `if($row['price, code']=='1, 5')`

You need do `if($row['price'] == 1 && $row['code'] == 5)`

And use mysqli for mysql is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for answer me. But the code doesn't work yet. I did these changes and doesn't show any picture yet. Any suggestion? Do you have some "example"?

Comment: Execute on console?

Comment: the mysql_query is deprecated that's why he is getting empty data from database

Comment: @RamsésFernández Thanks for answer me, I changed everything, but is not working yet. I have edited my post.

Comment: @AbidNawaz Thanks for the tip, I have changed. Can you see my post now? Thanks man! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Gabriel post here the $results output. use print_r($results);exit; to show the printed array.

Comment: @AbidNawaz The result page?

Comment: Your path is correct? `'<img src="/images/'.$photo->t1.png.'"/>` are you sure that is `/images`?

Comment: after $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); put print_r($results);exit;  then refresh the page and  see whats there ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz When I put the print_r($results);exit; the page has gone "crazy", appears messy information and no image. The path is correct, inside the main folder I have a folder called "images". Thanks again Abid

Comment: You are using absolute path `/images` use only `images`

Comment: The information printed by print_r() function does not contains the images ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz If I understand, the answer is no. They are numeric values and if they are the ones I need, it will show the image that is inside "images".

Comment: does the database table "Cod_Codes" have images field ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz  No, none have.

Comment: $photo where from this variable comes. i think you have invalid image path.
and $photo->t1.png is also invalid you cant use key as t1.png.
try this <img src="images/your image name'"/> and this <img src="../images/your image name"/>